# Upstream trace in geometric network by number of segments

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, geometric-network

I am using a geometric network of a sanitary sewer. I am trying to determine the source of grease in the individual sewer segments. I know which segments that have been impacted by grease. I am trying to find the next 10 upstream segments.  In a geometric network is there a way to conduct an upstream trace that only goes up 10 (or what ever number I choose) segments from the segment where the trace started?  I am not looking for a distance, I am looking to identify specific upstream segments. I am using ArcMap 10.2.2.

Comment: Given knowledge of a few items, you could run a select loop with a limit.  Basically, run a select query that loops through a max of 10 times, adding to a selection of features that touch.  Then remove from the selection any features that have an invert elevation lower than your beginning sewer line.  This would help find upstream lines.  You may need to watch for forcemains, but a pump station should probably be a new search location anyway.

Comment: Please note that this doesn't need a geometric network to work.  If you are working in ArcGIS, the geometric network is not ideal for sewer networks as it cannot resolve direction of flow for certain conditions like multiple outlets or loops in the system.